# What is the mongodb aggregate query for that?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, aggregate, mean-stack

Can anyone help me with? What is the right MongoDB aggregation query to get this data?

What if i get the result like this :

{
    "_id": 1000,
    "items":[
        "laptop",
        "mouse",
    ],
    ...
}

[image]

Comment: Hello Guys, What was the query if I want result like this :

{
 "_id": 1000,
 "items":[
  "laptop",
  "mouse",
 ],
 ...
}

Comment: Can you update expected result properly?  what is "_id": 1000 in your expected result?

Comment: I want result like this : { "_id": 1000, "items":[ "laptop", "mouse", ], ... }                                  Where id is coming from orders, I just only want to name of items from products collections, rest of all things is coming from "orders"

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking you have a collection with order which has a reference to products and you want to find all products for an order, is that it?

You probably want to use the `$lookup` in your aggregate pipeline, see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Since `items` is an array your must first use `$unwind`. So your aggregate pipeline would be something along the lines of:
`db.orders.aggregate([{$unwind:'items'},{$lookup:{from:'products',localField:'items',foreignField:'_id',as:'item_product'}}])`

You may have to adjust the query to fit your specific needs, but that's roughly what you need

Comment: What if i get the result like this :

{
 "_id": 1000,
 "items":[
  "laptop",
  "mouse",
 ],
 ...
}